# Unable to retrieving chat history using Strophe.js and Ejabberd with XEP-0313: Message Archive Management (MAM)

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, strophe.js

I'm currently working on a web-based chat application using Strophe.js as the XMPP client library and Ejabberd as the XMPP server. I'm attempting to implement support for retrieving chat history using XEP-0313: Message Archive Management (MAM), but I'm encountering difficulties.

My goal is to fetch the chat history for a particular user and display it in the chat interface. However, my current implementation seems to only return the count of messages, rather than the actual message content.

Here's a snippet of my code for retrieving the chat history:

```js
const iq = $iq({
  type: 'set',
  id: 'juliet1',
}).c('query', {
  xmlns: 'urn:xmpp:mam:2'
}).c('x', {
  xmlns: 'jabber:x:data',
  type: 'submit'
}).c('field', {
  var: 'FORM_TYPE',
  type: 'hidden'
}).c('value').t('urn:xmpp:mam:2').up().up().c('field', {
  var: 'with'
}).c('value').t(jid).up().tree();

connection.sendIQ(iq, function(response) {
   const message = response.getElementsByTagName('result');
   console.log(response);
   messages.forEach(message => {
      const body = Strophe.getText(message.querySelector("body"));
      const from = message.getAttribute('from');
      displayMessage(from, body);
   });
   return true;
});
```

The issue I'm facing is that response.getElementsByTagName('result') doesn't return any messages, when console logging response i am getting only -

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" to="dev@localhost/1178459894898988032171235" from="dev@localhost" type="result" id="juliet1">
  <fin xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:2" complete="true">
    <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
      <count>1</count>
      <first>1707854878326932</first>
      <last>1707854878326932</last>
    </set>
  </fin>
</iq>
```

I've double-checked my XMPP server configuration, and it seems to support MAM properly.

I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my code or if there's a better approach to retrieving chat history using Strophe.js and Ejabberd. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Strophe.js version: **1.6.0**

Ejabberd version: **23.10.0**

**ejabberd.yml**

```
mod_mam:
  ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
  ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
  ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
  ## db_type: sql
  assume_mam_usage: true
  default: always
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

**note:** - I have tested the query in Gajim XML console and it returns the messages.